# Space character at start of output in PHP/Smarty - how to track it?

Tags: php, csv, smarty

I am dealing with a rather large web app in PHP with smarty.  One part of it requires spitting out a report in CSV format.  I set all required headers and pass data to the smarty template:

```
$template->assign('headers', $report->get_headers());
$template->assign('data', $report->get_data());
```

My template looks like this:

```
{strip}
{assign var="newline" value="\n"}
{foreach from=$headers item=h name=hdr}
    "{$h|replace:'"':'""'}"
    {if !$smarty.foreach.hdr.last},{/if}
{/foreach}
{$newline}
{if trim($warntext) != ''} 
    "{$warntext|replace:'"':'""'}"
    {$newline}
{/if}
{foreach from=$data item=row name=res}
    {foreach from=$row item=v name=val}
        "{$v|replace:'"':'""'}"
        {if !$smarty.foreach.val.last},{/if}
    {/foreach}
    {if !$smarty.foreach.res.last}{$newline}{/if}
{/foreach}
{/strip}
```

Everything works fine - except one problem.  Somewhere there's one space character being printed in the very beginning of the output, so the first row in the CSV (headers) looks like this:

```
[space-char]"ID","Name","Reg date",...
```

As a result, Excel messes up the first heading: A1 cell contains `' "ID"'` (without the single quotes, of course).  Obviously, there's something somewhere printing this space char - but how can I find it?  I tried tracing the execution of the report (there are dozens of php files being `required` from inside each other - with a total of more than 10K lines of code to get the report).  I tried searching for `echo` and `print` and `print_r` - but nothing. I'm getting desperate now.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. Please do not comment/answer with "let them just fix the output file", as these are external clients I'm dealing with: I can't tell them to 'please edit the file before opening in Excel'.

Comment: If you fetch the output directly from smarty is the space there? or is the space being added to your output before the smarty template is rendered?

Comment: You can still fix it with an output filter: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Comment: Try looking for whitespaces right before opening `<?php` tags and right after closing `?>` tags (if used at all). These are common places to have spaces accidently.

Comment: in my experience this sort of thing is usually in my controller file (the php that assigns the template). You may just have a space character before the opening "<?php" tag, like " <?php". It's probably not in the smarty system files, or any of the other system files, and if you've already scoured your templates, then I would check the controller. You could "fix" it with an output buffer, like hakre says, but that's kind of hacky.

Comment: Ok, found it! It was a space char before `<?php` in one of the `model` files. @Jürgen you were the first to suggest search for this - if you post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking for whitespaces right before opening `<?php` tags and right after closing `?>` tags (if used at all). These are common places to have spaces accidently.